# Get label specific feature importances from Random Forest (and Decision Tree)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree

I want to retrieve label / class specific feature importances from a Random Forest or a Decision tree without training n_class times a one vs. rest model.
As a library I am using scikit-learn in Python. The models are an instance of either the `tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()` or `RandomForestClassifier()` class.
Since the `feature_importances_` attribute only returns the importance of each feature throughout the whole model, this is unfortunately not quite helpful for me!

Answer (score 0):

To get the label, you can create [`pandas.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) and assign index as the column names of training data. Important features returns by the [`RandomForestClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) is keeping the training data columns in the order.

```
rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500)
rfc.fit(X,y)
# In the following pandas series you can mention index as X.columns
importances = pd.Series(rfc.feature_importances_,index=X.columns)

print(importances)

Pclass      0.083675
Sex         0.190060
Age         0.234741
SibSp       0.051893
Parch       0.034452
Fare        0.254560
Embarked    0.031173
titles      0.119446
dtype: float64

print(X)
Pclass  Sex Age SibSp   Parch   Fare    Embarked    titles
0   3   0   22.000000   1   0   7.2500  0   12
1   1   1   38.000000   1   0   71.2833 1   13
2   3   1   26.000000   0   0   7.9250  0   9
3   1   1   35.000000   1   0   53.1000 0   13
4   3   0   35.000000   0   0   8.0500  0   12
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
886 2   0   27.000000   0   0   13.0000 0   15
887 1   1   19.000000   0   0   30.0000 0   9
888 3   1   29.699118   1   2   23.4500 0   9
889 1   0   26.000000   0   0   30.0000 1   12
890 3   0   32.000000   0   0   7.7500  2   12

print(X.columns)
>>> Index(['Pclass', 'Sex', 'Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch', 'Fare', 'Embarked', 'titles'], dtype='object')
```

Please refer [Feature importances with a forest of trees](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html) for more details

Comment: The OP wants to "retrieve label / class specific feature importances", that is, feature_importances for predicting one particular class in a multi-class output. Not all important features would be important to predict one of the classes. I don't think there is any better way than the one vs. rest model that the OP mentions.

Answer (score 0):

The build-in function "importance" should be used carefully! The importance can be calculated in many different ways: how often is a variable split on? What's the average impurity after a split for each variable etc. etc. i.e it is very important that you know *exactly* how the importance is calculated, and that you agree that it indeed correspond to your "importance"-understanding.

I would recommend looking at [shap](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for calculating the SHAP-values that gives a more robust and "correct" answer of the importances.